# How to route simultaneously in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express

In my `router` when I access `/quiz`, I'd like to render `quiz.ejs` and get quiz data by `doGetQuiz` to show them in `quiz.ejs`

I guess I must rewrite `router` in some way..

following my work..

```
router.get('/quiz',(req,res)=>{
    res.render("quiz");
});
router.get('/quiz',quizController.doGetQuiz);
```

Here is my `controller`

```
const Quizes = require("../models/Quizes");

module.exports = {
    doGetQuiz:function(req,res,next){
        Quizes.getQuiz(res);
        }
    };
```

Here is my model

```
const API_KEY="https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&type=multiple";
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const Quiz=require("../helpers/quiz");

module.exports={
    getQuiz:function(res){
      fetch(API_KEY)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => { const quiz = new Quiz(json); 
            res.json(quiz);
      });
    }
};
```

I guess I must combine them in `router`..

If someone has opinion,please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to use ajax or insert the data in ejs directly?

Comment: In this question,I searched to insert data in ejs.. But are there some way to get data by like `fetch(http://localhost:8000/quiz)`??  this means I practice to fetch both in front and back end.. thanks

Comment: Yes there is. The way is a url. You cannot have the same url for both the page and data. The data needs another url so do something like `router.get('/quizdata',quizController.doGetQuiz);` then fetch it `fetch('http://localhost:8000/quizdata')`

Comment: If you don't want to use fetch then don't create a separate controller for the data. Just do: `Quizes.getQuiz({json:(data) => { res.render("quiz", data); }})`. Of course if you remove `res.json()` in `getQuiz()` and just pass a regular callback you can do: `Quizes.getQuiz((data) => res.render("quiz", data))`. And instead of calling the second `.then()` inside `getQuiz()` you return the `fetch` you can do: `Quizes.getQuiz().then((data) => res.render("quiz", data))`

Comment: Thank you, the reason why I cannnot use same url is when access hit `/quiz` in router,then `routing` will processed from the top then the only first `/quiz` routing will work ?

Answer (score 1):

## Traditional

If you want to render the data directly in the ejs template you need to pass it as the second argument.

Delete the controller and modify your main route/controller to just:

```
// This is your main controller, routes and controllers mean the same
// thing so it is kind of stupid to have a controller call another controller
// unnecessarily

const Quizes = require("../models/Quizes");

router.get('/quiz',(req,res)=>{
    Quizes.getQuiz().then(data => {
        res.render("quiz", data);
    });
});
```

Now modify your model:

```
getQuiz: function(res){
   // THIS RETURN IS IMPORTANT to be able to use then in your controller
  return fetch(API_KEY)
      .then(response => response.json());
}
```

## Ajax

If instead you want to use ajax you need to give your quiz data a separate url:

```
router.get('/quiz-data',quizController.doGetQuiz);
```

Then you need to use something like `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest` to get that data:

```
fetch('/quiz-data').then(r => r.json).then( ... )
```

Comment: It seemed,When I access `/quiz`, the data will not be achieved , instead of `/quiz`,It seems that we must access`/quiz-data`. Where is wrong in my understanding ? Thanks

Comment: Your understanding of the HTTP protocol is a bit lacking. The protocol behind web pages is extremely simple - one request, one response. HTTP cannot support replying back two responses for a single request therefore you must make two requests if you want two responses. This means two URI - note that if you use query params you can make a single URL serve two URI eg: `/quiz` and `/quiz?data=true`. Because of the design of HTTP no programming language or framework can work the way you expected it to